# If $\Gamma\cup\{\sim(A\land B)\}$ is consistent, what can be said about $\Gamma\cup\{\sim(A\lor B)\},\Gamma\cup\{\sim A\},\Gamma\cup\{\sim B\}$?

Tags: logic, contest-math, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

The following question arose in the NOI of India Section taken a few days back:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a set of predicate formulas, and let $A, B$ be two predicate formulas; if the theory $\Gamma \cup \{ \sim (A \wedge B) \}$ is consistent, which of the following is true?
>
> 1) At most one of $\Gamma \cup \{ \sim (A \wedge B) \}$  or  $\Gamma \cup  \{ \sim (A \vee
>  B) \}$  is consistent.
>
> 2) At least one of  $\Gamma \cup  \{ \sim A \}$ or $\Gamma \cup  \{ \sim B \}$ is consistent.

Thanks to anyone...

Comment: For Γ∪ { ~ (A ∧ B)} to be *consistent*, we need a *valuation* $v$ such that for all formula $\gamma_i \in \Gamma$, $v(\gamma_i)=v(\sim (A ∧ B))=$ **t**. But $v(\sim (A ∧ B))=$ **t** if and only if $v(A ∧ B)=$ **f** and this means that $v(A)=$ **f** or $v(B)=$ **f**, i.e. $v(\sim A)=$ **t** or $v(\sim B)=$ **t**. Conclusion :  at least one of Γ∪ {~A} or Γ∪ {~B} is *consistent*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Would you please add any proof? any Solution Manual or Link of courses?

Comment: See Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013), page 6 and page 13 or Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&pg=PA159) (2003), page 159.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, infact what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: For 1., assuming that the problem was not "invented" by you, you have to separate the "linguistic haze" from the mathematical part. If Γ ∪ {∼(A∧B)} is *consistent*, then at least Γ∪{∼(A∧B)} is consistent. So the issue is : is it possible for Γ∪{∼(A∨B)} to be consistent also ?

Comment: If the answer is : YES, then the statement "at most" is false...

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, would you please add a bit more detail about differences? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at this from a semantic viewpoint, without getting bogged down in the details of any specific formalism (also motivated by the fact that you didn't specify a formalism).

So we have a model $\mathcal M$ for $\Gamma$ that is also a model for $\neg(A \land B)$. That is, $A$ and $B$ are not **both** true in $\mathcal M$.

As to 1., since $\mathcal M$ already testifies the first of the two to be consistent, it can only be true if we can prove $\Gamma$ and $\neg(A \lor B)$ cannot be simultaneously satisfied. However, considering the case $A = B$, where $A \land B \equiv A \lor B$, we see that $\mathcal M$ may very well be a model for the second theory as well. Thus, 1. is false.

To prove 2., we have to find a model for $\Gamma$ and at least one of $\neg A$ and $\neg B$. But we already saw that $\mathcal M$ cannot model both of $A$ and $B$. So it must be a model of at least one of $\neg A$ and $\neg B$.

In conclusion, 1. is false while 2. is true.